# How to align cells in Android Tablelayout to the right

Tags: android, alignment, cell, tablelayout

i have a problem with the TableLayout in Android. I want something like this: [image: that is how it should look like]

but i dont get it to work :( i tried

```
android:layout_weight
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
```

but it still doesnt work. Does anyone has an idea?
That's my xml so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="de.elpudge.lbp.StartActivityModules">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonStartModulesMore"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/start_button_more_selector"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/modules"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonStartModulesMore"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/buttonStartModulesPlay"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/start_button_play_selector"/>

        </TableRow>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: add your xml please

Comment: sorry! AAAAND done :D